# Failed to install Kali Linux by USB drive

Tags: linux, usb

I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop with Windows 10. I downloaded 64 Bit Kali Linux 2018.1 and when I try to install it from a USB I get the following error message:

```
There was a problem reading data from the CD-ROM. Please make sure it is in the drive. If retrying does not work, you should check the integrity of your CD-ROM.
```

I tried running the following command but it doesn't work, and it shows the message in the screenshot.

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /cdrom
```

[image: There was a problem reading data from the CD-ROM Error Message]

Answer (score 4):

Go back to your computer and use Rufus to create a bootable USB drive from the Kali Linux ISO. Plug it back into your Toshiba and boot from your USB. That should work.

This is very, very important to anyone else who has this issue: You need to have Rufus work in DD mode, *not* ISO mode. If it's ISO mode it won't work properly!

Comment: This worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to execute shell:

```
mkdir /usb
mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /usb
mount /usb /cdrom
```

These three lines solved the problem when using Rufus in ISO mode.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to move forward a bit using the following command:

```
touch /dev/sr0
ln -f /dev/sdb1 /dev/sr0
```

From there I was able to get past it detecting the CD-ROM. However it didnt get me far as the next screen says "UNetbootin media detected" which basically says I will likely have problems, the screen after this greets me with the same error. You can execute:

```
umount /cdrom
```

let it detect and it will present the same error after the unetbootin message again. So... I only got further by one screen. Validation of the media fails as the message says "Not a valid debian installation media". So I will punt and snag a removable dvd drive and just do it that way. Live CD functions all work but have been unable to do any installs even from text.

Also, this works via <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f2</kbd> or using the shell from the menu.